Сделать выравнивание хедера таблицы из mui, react
У меня есть такая таблица из библиотеки material ui
        <Table id='consumption-data'>
            <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCellStyled align='left'>Month</TableCellStyled>
                    <TableCellStyled>Item 1</TableCellStyled>
                    <TableCellStyled>Item 2</TableCellStyled>
                    <TableCellStyled>Item 3</TableCellStyled>
                    <TableCellStyled>Item 4</TableCellStyled>
                </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCellStyled>Jan</TableCellStyled>
                    <TableCellStyled>3163</TableCellStyled>
                    <TableCellStyled>3163</TableCellStyled>
                    <TableCellStyled>3163</TableCellStyled>
                    <TableCellStyled>3163</TableCellStyled>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>Feb</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>Mar</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>Apr</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>May</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>Jun</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>3163</TableCell>
                </TableRow>

                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>...</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>...</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>...</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>...</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>...</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            </TableBody>
        </Table>

сейчас хедер таблицы находится сверху, а можно ли сделать чтобы хедер таблицы был сбоку слева и получается все значения должны идти по строчно, слева на право

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67667659/12377476

ага, спасибо...
